# What is the difference between xcode and ios sdk?

Tags: xcode, ios

My project is not running on xcode3.2 with ios SDK3.2 but working fine in xcode3.2 with ios SDK4.2.

Please can any one explain me What is the difference between xcode and ios sdk?

Comment: xcode is the interface where u code for iphone app..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XCode is an IDE. iOS SDK (Software Development Kit) is a set of development tools (mostly in the form of libraries) that you use to create applications with.

As mentioned by @VladTheImpaler you are probably trying to open an application written with the iOS4.2 SDK in an environment that only has the iOS3.2 SDK libraries. This will cause incompatibilities and missing links etc.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know XCode is the program that you are using to write and compile. The different SDKs are containing the different APIs for what you're writing.

So probably you are using stuff that is supported in 4.2 but isn't in 3.2 of iOS and since the APIs are missing, that's why it is not running.

Answer (score 1):

HI this may help you.

xcode is the interface where u code for iphone app..

ios sdk is somulator of iphone.

**one Xcode contain more then one ios sdk.**

here xcode 4 contain ios sdk 3.2,4.0.2,4.1,.4.2,4.3

[image]